# SQL 'CASE' Clause - Column Name Names Itself CASE

Tags: sql, case, firebird

I'm trying to SELECT multiple columns from my table 'EXAMPLE_1' and call a CASE-expression on one of them.

When executing it shows every column as it's supposed to, but the one I called the CASE-expression on has the name 'CASE'.

How do I fix this? I can't find any typos causing this.

```
SELECT
    NAME AS LAST_NAME,
    FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME,
    BIRTH_DATE AS BIRTH_DATE,
    CASE UPPER(BUNDESLAND)
        WHEN 'BW' THEN 'Baden-Wuerttemberg'
        WHEN 'BY' THEN 'Bayern'
        WHEN 'BE' THEN 'Berlin'
        WHEN 'BB' THEN 'Brandenburg'
        WHEN 'HB' THEN 'Bremen'
        WHEN 'HH' THEN 'Hamburg'
        WHEN 'HE' THEN 'Hessen'
        WHEN 'MV' THEN 'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'
        WHEN 'NI' THEN 'Niedersachsen'
        WHEN 'NW' THEN 'Nordrhein-Westfalen'
        WHEN 'RP' THEN 'Rheinland-Pflaz'
        WHEN 'SL' THEN 'Saarland'
        WHEN 'SN' THEN 'Sachsen'
        WHEN 'ST' THEN 'Sachsen-Anhalt'
        WHEN 'SH' THEN 'Schleswig-Holstein'
        WHEN 'TH' THEN 'Thüringen'

        ELSE ' '
    END

FROM EXAMPLE_1;
```

Do I have to put the column 'Bundesland' in the SELECT before calling the CASE-expression?

Comment: won't it be better to have a dictionary table and to `join` it instead of arbitrary and long `case` ? the added benefit will be an option to set a `Foreign Key` - a warranty that any "short" value would have full name for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name is being assigned by the server because you haven't explicitly given the derived column a name. If you want the column name to display as `BUNDESLAND`, then you will have to assign that as an alias to the `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
    NAME AS LAST_NAME,
    FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME,
    BIRTH_DATE AS BIRTH_DATE,
    CASE UPPER(BUNDESLAND)
        WHEN 'BW' THEN 'Baden-Wuerttemberg'
        WHEN 'BY' THEN 'Bayern'
        WHEN 'BE' THEN 'Berlin'
        WHEN 'BB' THEN 'Brandenburg'
        WHEN 'HB' THEN 'Bremen'
        WHEN 'HH' THEN 'Hamburg'
        WHEN 'HE' THEN 'Hessen'
        WHEN 'MV' THEN 'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'
        WHEN 'NI' THEN 'Niedersachsen'
        WHEN 'NW' THEN 'Nordrhein-Westfalen'
        WHEN 'RP' THEN 'Rheinland-Pflaz'
        WHEN 'SL' THEN 'Saarland'
        WHEN 'SN' THEN 'Sachsen'
        WHEN 'ST' THEN 'Sachsen-Anhalt'
        WHEN 'SH' THEN 'Schleswig-Holstein'
        WHEN 'TH' THEN 'Thüringen'

        ELSE ' '
    END AS BUNDESLAND        --<---- Here.

FROM EXAMPLE_1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @pushpeakpop, I'm glad that you found the answer useful. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left (and/or upvoting by clicking the grey "up" arrow). Accepting an answer gives us each some reputation points, and lets others know what worked for you.

Comment: It is not actually the IDE that assigns this name, it is the Firebird server that does it for expressions without an alias.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkRotteveel. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want this

```
SELECT
    NAME AS LAST_NAME,
    FIRST_NAME AS FIRST_NAME,
    BIRTH_DATE AS BIRTH_DATE,
    (CASE UPPER(BUNDESLAND)
        WHEN 'BW' THEN 'Baden-Wuerttemberg'
        WHEN 'BY' THEN 'Bayern'
        WHEN 'BE' THEN 'Berlin'
        WHEN 'BB' THEN 'Brandenburg'
        WHEN 'HB' THEN 'Bremen'
        WHEN 'HH' THEN 'Hamburg'
        WHEN 'HE' THEN 'Hessen'
        WHEN 'MV' THEN 'Mecklenburg-Vorpommern'
        WHEN 'NI' THEN 'Niedersachsen'
        WHEN 'NW' THEN 'Nordrhein-Westfalen'
        WHEN 'RP' THEN 'Rheinland-Pflaz'
        WHEN 'SL' THEN 'Saarland'
        WHEN 'SN' THEN 'Sachsen'
        WHEN 'ST' THEN 'Sachsen-Anhalt'
        WHEN 'SH' THEN 'Schleswig-Holstein'
        WHEN 'TH' THEN 'Thüringen'

        ELSE ' '
    END) AS Bundesland_Long

FROM EXAMPLE_1;
```

Thus giving an **alias** to your case statement. I named it differently than your original `BUNDESLAND` column, because some RDBMS don't like this, and I don't know your RDBMS

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for the hint on not matching alias name with actual column name :)

Comment: Using an alias identical to a column name is fine in Firebird. There is also no need for parentheses around the case expression.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You indeed never need  parenthesis for an alias, however I consider it a good practice as it adds clarity to your code. Its like mixing AND and OR without parenthesis just because you know by heart the operators precedence: it works, but its not a good practice ;)

Comment: I think the delineation added by CASE and END is sufficient, but I agree this is opinion. I just noticed it because the question doesn't have it.